# pure css sub menu fly out in joomla

Tags: css, joomla2.5, submenu

I have created a pure css drop down menu with two levels. The first level works fine. But the second level, which has to fly out to the left of the parent li, appears in a fixed position above the li.
Pls refer http://joomlaosw.oswebware.com/ (Menu item "About Template")

As you would observe all fly out submenu's position is fixed for all the li's. I want the fly out sub menu to appear in line with the parent li.
PS: Am not familiar with jQuery yet, thats why i have gone for a pure css menu.

Pls give me your valuable suggestions.

This is my first template so any suggestions to improve my work also would be welcome (apart from the main issue).
Thanks in advance.
Anu

Note this is just the relevant part of the code... U can check it using firebug or i will send the full code if required...

html code

```
    <ul class="menu ">
    <li class="item-101 current active"><a href="/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-109 deeper parent"><a href="/">About Template</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="item-103 deeper parent"><a href="/index.php/2013-09-14-00-17-18/typography">Typography</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="item-125"><a href="/">Sub Menu I</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="item-112 deeper parent"><a href="/index.php/2013-09-14-00-17-18/module-positions">Module Positions</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="item-126"><a href="/">Sub Menu II</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="item-113 deeper parent"><a href="/index.php/2013-09-14-00-17-18/styles">Styles</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="item-121"><a href="/index.php/2013-09-14-00-17-18/styles/blue">Blue</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="item-123"><a href="/index.php/2013-09-14-00-17-18/styles/green">Green</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="item-124"><a href="/index.php/2013-09-14-00-17-18/styles/black">Black</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="item-122"><a href="/index.php/2013-09-14-00-17-18/styles/red">Red</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item-110"><a href="/">Buy Now</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-111"><a href="/">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
    .menu {
    margin: 100px auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.menu ul {
    display: none !important;
}
.menu ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
.menu li:hover > ul {
    display: block !important;
    top: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
}
.menu ul {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 0 20px;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
    margin-top: -5px !important;
    z-index:3;
}
.menu ul li {
    float: left;
}
.menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 25px 40px;
    color: #757575;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu ul ul {
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left:100%;
}
.menu ul ul li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.menu ul ul li a {
    padding: 15px 40px;
    color: #fff;
}
.deeper.parent ul li a {
    border: medium none !important;
    padding: 15px 0 0 !important;
    margin-top: -5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your menu portion html code and css for it.